Is this considered a valid sequence in Mathematics?
Let the terms be $n^2$ when $n \leq 4$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ when $n>5$
Therefore the terms will be $(1,4,9,16,1/5,1/6,1/7,\ldots)$ and the terms eventually converges to $0$.
Is this a valid sequence?

Yes. This is valid as it is defined for every natural number.

Why wouldn't it be valid? It isn't ambiguous.

A sequence in math is simply an ordered list of objects where repetitions are allowed (as opposed to, say, a set). There's no restriction that terms must follow a certain formula or anything of the sort.
